# hibernate fail to retrieve and create some of the fields

Tags: java, angularjs, hibernate, jersey

I have created a simple Java RESTful that leans on Hibernate with jersey and MYSQL database, frontend is a simple list creation form with a the list itself being pulled from the database.
the entire project is running on Apache Tomcat 8.0 on my localhost.

the first problem begins when fetching data from mysql the hibernate seem to fail pulling the last 3 fields from the database and they show as nulls as seen in this picture

[image]

and if I try to Edit/Update or add a new row I get the following error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ws.ApplicationConfig] in
>   context with path [/CRUDAngularJS_Server] threw exception
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The entity must not be null   at
>   javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity.(GenericEntity.java:89)  at
>   ws.ProductRestful$1.(ProductRestful.java:19)    at
>   ws.ProductRestful.findAll(ProductRestful.java:19)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Product.java

```
    package entities;

// Generated Jun 19, 2015 2:28:36 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 * Product generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "product", catalog = "demo")
@XmlRootElement(name = "product")
public class Product implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String service;
    private String startdate;
    private String enddate;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String name, String email, String phone, String service, String startdate, String enddate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.service = service;
        this.startdate = startdate;
        this.enddate = enddate;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 65535)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 65535)
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = false, length = 65535)
    public String getPhone() {
        return this.phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Column(name = "service", nullable = false, length = 65535)
    public String getService() {
        return this.service;
    }

    public void setService(String service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Column(name = "startdate", nullable = false, length = 65535)
    public String getStartDate() {
        return this.startdate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(String startdate) {
        this.startdate = startdate;
    }

    @Column(name = "enddate", nullable = false, length = 65535)
    public String getEndDate() {
        return this.enddate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(String enddate) {
        this.enddate = enddate;
    }

}
```

index.html (angularjs code inside aswell)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>CRUD Java Restful Web Service and AngularJS</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="productController">

<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Service</th>
        <th>Start sate</th>
        <th>End sate</th>
        <th>Option</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in result">
        <td>{{product.id}}</td>
        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
        <td>{{product.email}}</td>
        <td>{{product.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{product.service}}</td>
        <td>{{product.startdate}}</td>
        <td>{{product.enddate}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" ng-click="del(product.id)">Delete</a> | 
            <a href="#" ng-click="edit(product)">Edit</a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Product Information</legend>
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="product.name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="product.email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="product.phone"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Service</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="product.service"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Start date</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="product.startdate"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>End date</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="product.enddate"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="add()"> 
                <input type="button" value="Update" ng-click="update()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

    myapp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
            delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        }
    ]);

    myapp.controller('productController', function($scope, $http){

        $scope.base_url = 'http://localhost:8080/CRUDAngularJS_Server/rest/product/';

        $http.get($scope.base_url + 'findall').success(function(response){
            $scope.result = response.product;
        });

        $scope.add = function(){
            $http.post($scope.base_url + 'create', $scope.product).success(function(response) {
                alert('Done');
            });     
        };

        $scope.del = function(id){
            var result = confirm('Are you sure?');
            if(result===true) {
                $http.delete($scope.base_url + 'delete/' + id).success(function(response) {
                    alert('Done');
                }); 
            }
        };

        $scope.edit = function(product){
            $scope.product = product;
        };

        $scope.update = function() {
            $http.put($scope.base_url + 'edit', $scope.product).success(function(response) {
                alert('Done');
            });     
        };

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Would appreciate any help or a clue, I've been searching for a solution for the past 16 hours and it drives me crazy.
if any specific code is requires let me know and ill gladly add it in here.

EDIT 1::

ok so I managed to fix the Service tab not working as it was a typo in the code at Product.java which leads me to think that because the Start date and End date are 2 words maybe the mapping is messed up somewhere on the way, but I cant find the place to point at sadly...

Edit 2 ::

ProductRestful.java

```
package ws;

import entities.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import model.*;

@Path("product")
public class ProductRestful {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/findall")
    public Response findAll() {
        ProductModel pm = new ProductModel();
        return Response
                .ok()
                .entity(new GenericEntity<List<Product>>(pm.findAll()) {
                })
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                        "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD").build();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/find/{id}")
    public Response find(@PathParam(value = "id") String id) {
        ProductModel pm = new ProductModel();
        Product p = pm.find(Integer.valueOf(id));
        if (p == null)
            return null;
        return Response
                .ok()
                .entity(new GenericEntity<Product>(p) {
                })
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                        "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD").build();
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/create")
    public Response create(Product p) {
        ProductModel pm = new ProductModel();
        pm.create(p);
        return Response
                .ok()
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                        "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD").build();
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/delete/{id}")
    public Response delete(@PathParam(value = "id") String id) {
        ProductModel pm = new ProductModel();
        pm.delete(pm.find(Integer.valueOf(id)));
        return Response
                .ok()
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                        "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD").build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/edit")
    public Response edit(Product p) {
        ProductModel pm = new ProductModel();
        pm.update(p);
        return Response
                .ok()
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                        "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD").build();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the type of date fields in DB?

Comment: they are all set to TEXT as it seemed to be the most general thing I can set them to, they are also all with utf8_unicode_ci as the collation.

Comment: you seem to have 2 problems here : first fetching the 3 columns (can you trace the generated JSON ?) ... 2nd, creating a new entry, which seems to be null ... can you post the creation code here ? (angular js, rest call)

Comment: the angularjs code is in the index.html file and I will add the rest call aswell now, also you can see I managed to solve the problem with the Service tab. by the way i'm pretty sure that somewhere along the way the mapping of the database is what mess it all up...